# Change cell value based on checkbox in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Sample Sheet]

I'm using Google sheet to manage my budget (see sample below) where I add each of my expenses as a single entry (yes, sounds like a lot of work). I sometimes split the expense with my roommate but then I have to add the value and divide by 2 everytime.

I was thinking if I could use a checkbox next to the value that will automatically divide the expense number by 2 when I check it. Is this possible?

I'm open to simple suggestions other than the checkbox to automatically update the value. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using simple IF formula you can just check if the checkbox is true, if it is then it will divide the current value on column C by 2. Otherwise it will remain blank.

**Formula:**

```
=IF(D1,C1/2,"")
```

Drag down to other cells.

**Result:**
[image]

---

---

**Suggestion, Alternate solution:**

If you'd like you can make a table with a column for your roommate, instead of editing the actual column so you can see both values. And use this formula:

```
=if(NOT(D2=""),E2/2,E2)
```

You have a column for per head contribution/split. If the cell on roommate is blank then it will stay as the total value, if roommate has an additional then it will be added to total and split it by 2.
[image]

**Or using arrayformula:**

`=arrayformula(if(NOT(D2:D=""),E2:E/2,E2:E))`

Works the same as above you just have to fill the enter the formula in the first cell no need to drag down and it will automatically expand to rows/cells below just make sure that below cells are empty or it will return an error.

[image]

### Additional - Using same cell

As you've mentioned in the comments. Here's a way to divide the original value without using another cell to store it. (Not recommended)

**Formula:**

```
=VALUE/IF(D1,2,1)
```

example:

```
=1000/IF(D1,2,1)
```

**Result:**
[image]

However, I do not recommend this. It is still best to make use of another cell to store the original value before making calculations to it.

Also, using this formula you have to change the value from the formula  and not on the cell otherwise you will replace the actual formula.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not looking to add another column for my roommate. Is there a way to modify the value in the original cell? In case I don't want to use another column to show the split value.

Comment: @SurajBhatia what do you mean modify the value in the original cell? Aside from manually editing it, how do you want to modify it?

Comment: Do you mean that when checkbox is ticked it will replace the original cell with the value divide by 2?

Comment: @SurajBhatia I have edited my post to add the formula without using another cell. Let me know if this works. Note: It is not recommended and not the best practice.

Comment: @SurajBhatia If your concern is resolved please accept an answer which works best for you by clicking the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can try array approach-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(D1:D,C1:C/2,C1:C))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Is there a way to modify the value in the original cell? In case I don't want to use another column to show the split value.

Comment: Then you have to use AppScript. Functions can not modify any cell value.